# Is it possible to make IfFile work on Apache 2.4.29 for Ubuntu 18.04, and if so, how?

Tags: apache-2.4, conditional

I am wanting to conditionally load VirtualHosts depending on the existance of the appropriate key files required for SSL for that virtualhost (or failing which, have a generic certificate I can fall back to), and I've been unable to find a way to get Apache to do this.

I have come across the  directive, which would appear to be what I'm  looking for, but it keeps on complaining "Invalid command '

I'm using Apache 2.4.29 (Ubuntu) as packaged with Ubuntu 18.04.

I've tried configuring  outside the  directives, and also within it, bracketting the SSL configuration files.

It occurs to me that I might be missing a module, but according to my reading of the documentation this should be included in the [core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#iffile) of Apache.

Can anyone shine light on why I IfFile is failing for me?

Comment: It says right there "Available in 2.4.34 and later".

Comment: Yes, I *just noticed that*, and that is indeed the problem.   Do you want to post this as an answer ?  (Using ppa:ondrej/apache2 allowed me to upgrade to this version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation of IfFile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#iffile) says:

> Available in 2.4.34 and later.

The best solution is to upgrade your Apache.